# Error on line -1?

Tags: c++, class, object

I have a class called PID. I #include the header for the class. I have been using this class in various files including the file the error points to. The compiler complains about defining the function declaration itself `void dispPid(char *name, PID &pid){}`. All the contents of the function are commented out. The error reads `AutoTrucker:-1: error: 'PID' has not been declared` with no other errors. Commenting out the function in its entirety removes the error completely, compiles and works fine.

What really gets me confused is that:

1. The error points to line -1
2. The file exists, and is included
3. I use this PID class in right above as a pointer:

```
PID *pid;
if (chk(arg2,"roll")){pid = &aircraft.ap.pid.wingLeveler;}
else if (chk(arg2,"heading") || chk(arg2,"hdg")){pid = &aircraft.ap.pid.headingHold;}
else if (chk(arg2,"pitch")){pid = &aircraft.ap.pid.pitchHold;}
...
```

This code specified directly above compiles and works properly. So what gives?

**EDIT 2:**
This is such a jimmy rig it makes me sick. But is does solve the problem for the time being. So what gives? The compiler does not like the PID class as a function argument, but it finds it acceptable inside the function? I would really like to find a **proper** solution to this instead of passing in a void pointer and converting it!

```
void dispPid(const char *name, void *tpid)
{
  PID &pid = *((PID*)tpid);
  ...
}
```

**EDIT:** (adding in some more source code as requested)

```
void cmdsPid(char *buffer)
{
  if (chk(buffer,"pid"))
  {
    char *arg1 = next(buffer);
    if (chk(arg1,"ls"))
    {
      char *arg2 = next(arg1);
      if (chk(arg2,"") || chk(arg2,"all"))
      {
        /*
        Serial.println("Listing all PIDs:");
        dispPid("Roll",aircraft.ap.pid.wingLeveler);
        Serial.print("\t");
        dispPid("Heading",aircraft.ap.pid,headingHold);
        dispPid("Pitch",aircraft.ap.pid,pitchHold);
        Serial.print("\t");
        dispPid("V-Rate",aircraft.ap.pid.climbHold);
        Serial.print("\t\t");
        dispPid("Altitude",aircraft.ap.pid.altHold);
        dispPid("Throttle",aircraft.ap.pid.throttleHold);
        dispPid("Slip",aircraft.ap.pid.slipHold);
        */
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.print("Unknown argument");
      }
    }
    else if (chk(arg1,"w"))
    {
      char *arg2 = next(arg1);//name
      char *arg3 = next(arg2);//attr
      char *arg4 = next(arg3);//val
      double val = 0.0;
      bool onoff = false;
      if (chk(arg3,"inv"))
      {
        onoff = (chk(arg4,"off") || chk(arg4,"-"));
      }
      else if (chk(arg3,"max") || chk(arg3,"min"))
      {
        if (chk(arg4,"off") || chk(arg4,"-"))
        {
          onoff = false;
        }
        else
        {
          onoff = true;
          val = parseDoubleArg(arg4);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        val = parseDoubleArg(arg4);
      }
      PID *pid;
      if (chk(arg2,"roll")){pid = &aircraft.ap.pid.wingLeveler;}
      else if (chk(arg2,"heading") || chk(arg2,"hdg")){pid = &aircraft.ap.pid.headingHold;}
      else if (chk(arg2,"pitch")){pid = &aircraft.ap.pid.pitchHold;}
      else if (chk(arg2,"vrate")){pid = &aircraft.ap.pid.climbHold;}
      else if (chk(arg2,"alt")){pid = &aircraft.ap.pid.altHold;}
      else if (chk(arg2,"th")||chk(arg2,"thr")||chk(arg2,"thro")||chk(arg2,"throttle")){pid = &aircraft.ap.pid.throttleHold;}
      else if (chk(arg2,"slip")){pid = &aircraft.ap.pid.slipHold;}
      if (chk(arg3,"p")){pid->setPGain(val);}
      else if (chk(arg3,"i")){pid->setIGain(val);}
      else if (chk(arg4,"d")){pid->setDGain(val);}
      else if (chk(arg4,"max"))
      {
        if (onoff){pid->setLimitMax(val);}
        else{pid->disableMaxLimit();}
      }
      else if (chk(arg4,"min"))
      {
        if (onoff){pid->setLimitMin(val);}
        else{pid->disableMinLimit();}
      }
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Unknown argument");
    }
  }
}

void dispPid(char *name, PID &pid){}
```

The PID class (header):

```
#pragma once

#define PID_VERSION "1.1"

#include <inttypes.h>

#define allowLimitMax 1
#define allowLimitMin 2
#define invert 4
#define enabled 8

class PID
{
private:
    double pGain,iGain,dGain;
    double integrator;
    double *input,*output,*setpoint;
    double lastInput;
    double limitMax,limitMin;

    char settings;

public:
    struct Spid {
        double p,i,d,limitMax,limitMin;
        char settings;
    };

    PID();//constructor

    //getters
    double getPGain();
    double getIGain();
    double getDGain();
    double getLimitMax();
    double getLimitMin();
    bool isLimitMaxSet();
    bool isLimitMinSet();
    bool isInverted();

    //setters
    void setPGain(double newPGain);
    void setIGain(double newIGain);
    void setDGain(double newDGain);
    void setPIDGain(double newPGain, double newIGain, double newDGain);
    void setInput(double *newInput);
    void setOutput(double *newOutput);
    void setSetpoint(double *newSetpoint);
    void setIOS(double *newInput, double *newOutput, double *newSetpoint);
    void setLimitMax(double newLimitMax);
    void setLimitMin(double newLimitMin);
    void setLimits(double newLimitMin, double newLimitMax);
    void disableMaxLimit();
    void disableMinLimit();
    void disableLimits();
    void zeroOutIntegrator();
    void nullOut();
    void setInverted(bool newInvert);

    //actions
    void run();
    void run(double dt);

    void setFrom(Spid copy);
    void copy(Spid &copy);
};
```

Comment: Having the full source would help, seeing as this is probably a code ordering issue.

Comment: Could you show more of your .cpp and .h files? Specifically around the function signature

Comment: You might want to show the actual error you get—and tell us which compiler and platform you're on, and how you're invoking it.

Comment: @JeffWatkins The files are rather large. I'm not sure to what extent is needed, but I included some more of the source as an edit.

Comment: Is PID.h is included in source file declaring dispPid() ?

Comment: Are you by any chance compiling the file includind dispPid as C instead of C++ (e.g., by naming it "pid.c" and using all the default make rules or vcproj settings or whatever)?

Comment: @abarnert I do mention the exact error. `AutoTrucker:-1: error: 'PID' has not been declared`. The compiler is the Arduino IDE 1.0. What triggers the error was also specified in the question. Declaring the function with the PID reference variable as an argument causes the error. Removing the line fixes it.

Comment: @abarnert Wow. The source has to be C++ for many reasons. But the primary ones are that I use references and classes. Compiling in C would not do me any good. And the Arduino IDE compiles in C++.

Comment: Arduino IDE isn't a compiler, it's an IDE. What compiler is it invoking? It must have some kind of build log that shows us the command line used to invoke the compiler and the full output of that command.

Comment: @jakebird451: You showed us one function that compiles, and one that doesn't. The one that compiles uses no references, and could be perfect C if there were a struct PID defined somewhere. The one that fails to compile could not be C. And does the Arduino IDE really compile in C++ even if you give it C files?

Comment: @abarnert The Arduino IDE implies that I am using AvrDude. And it uses predefined rulesets such as C++, certain libraries, etc etc. I know that Arduino is not the compiler, I just imply.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question: what is the command line used to invoke the compiler, and what is the output of that command? If you'd rather argue about why you shouldn't have to answer, you can wait for someone else.

Comment: @abarnert The pid library in a class. That needs to compile in C++. The file that is referencing the class is the Arduino .ino file, and compiles as a c++ file. I cannot use a C file to reference a class.

Comment: @abarnert The Arduino IDE does not allow you to modify too much for the compilation process. All I can provide you with is the verbose output. It performs a clean compile each time for each file (even libraries) using commands similar to `avr-g++ -c -g -Os -Wall -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -mmcu=atmega2560 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=100 -I/.../hardware/arduino/cores/arduino -I/.../hardware/arduino/variants/mega -I/.../libraries/SPI /var/folders/.../T/build2985697059833162490.tmp/AutoTrucker.cpp -o/var/folders/.../build2985697059833162490.tmp/AutoTrucker.cpp.o`

Comment: Try declaring `PID& test = *pid;` in your working function.

Comment: @rasmus It seems to compile just fine. I put in in right after the declaration of the pointer.

Comment: @rasmus I provided an edit in my question about my temporary fix.

Comment: Must be a bug in the compiler.